# How to display the sum of every row and column in a table in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python program that creates a 10 by 10 table (array) and automatically populates that table with 100 random integers that range from 1 to 250. The program should then display the sum of every row and column for this table.

My program currently outputs a table with 100 random integers, along with the sum of each row. It fails however to produce the sum of each column.

```
import random

dash = "-" * 62

print("Random Integer Table:")

print(dash)
print("{:<10s} {:>45s}".format("RANDOM INTEGERS", "ROW TOTAL"))
print(dash)

for rows in range(10):
    random_list = [random.randrange(1,251, 1) for rows in range(10)]
    stringList = [str(i) for i in random_list]
    row_total = sum(random_list)

    print("{:<3} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4}".format(stringList[0], stringList[1], stringList[2], stringList[3], stringList[4], stringList[5], stringList[6], stringList[7], stringList[8], stringList[9]), "{:17d}".format(row_total))

print(dash)
print("COLUMN TOTAL")
print(dash)

sum(random_list(zip([0])))
```

The program currently outputs the following:

```
Random Integer Table:
--------------------------------------------------------------
RANDOM INTEGERS                                     ROW TOTAL
--------------------------------------------------------------
71    29   33   69    6  188  167  158  126               892
100  114  109   89  237  168   25  201   43              1173
91    51   62  220   63   10   85   79  104               796
54   189   69   36  218  130  204   76   93              1289
113   36  104   81   18  215   53  169  103               925
92    20  206   16  116   69  237  168  212              1253
116   86  115   62  189  234  158  240  207              1602
35   101  234   25   41  136   73  154  197              1102
97    81   13   86   26  140  220   42  180              1132
118  117  134  170  237  212   89  140  124              1529
--------------------------------------------------------------
COLUMN TOTAL
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

However an error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

is present in line 30 (the last line) of my code, when attempting to print the totals for each column. Any way I can properly sum these columns and/or increase efficiency of my program? Thanks.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. You are trying to call a list, which isn't callable here: `random_list(zip([0]))`.  If you are trying to use the `zip` transpose trick, you have it backwards.

Comment: It's the `sum(random_list(zip([0])))` line. Python thinks that `random_list` is a callable because you entered `zip[0]` in the form of a parameter.

Comment: Because `random_list` is the last row of you matrix.

Comment: Ok, I understand how `sum(random_list(zip([0])))` produces an error, thank you. Would there be any other possible way to sum the columns since this method is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to save the sum of the column at the same time you iterave over each row.
Here is one way to do:

```
import random
dash = "-" * 62

print("Random Integer Table:")

print(dash)
print("{:<10s} {:>45s}".format("RANDOM INTEGERS", "ROW TOTAL"))
print(dash)
# Initialize a list that will have the sum of each column
sum_col = [0 for _ in range(10)]

for rows in range(10):
    random_list = [random.randrange(1, 251, 1) for rows in range(10)]

    # Save the current sum of each columns
    sum_col = [x + sum_part for x, sum_part in zip(random_list, sum_col)]

    stringList = [str(i) for i in random_list]
    row_total = sum(random_list)

    print("{:<3} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4}".format(stringList[0], stringList[1], stringList[2], stringList[
          3], stringList[4], stringList[5], stringList[6], stringList[7], stringList[8], stringList[9]), "{:17d}".format(row_total))

print(dash)
print("COLUMN TOTAL")
print(dash)

print("{:<3} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4}".format(sum_col[0], sum_col[1], sum_col[2], sum_col[
    3], sum_col[4], sum_col[5], sum_col[6], sum_col[7], sum_col[8], sum_col[9]), "{:17d}".format(sum(sum_col)))

# Random Integer Table:
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# RANDOM INTEGERS                                     ROW TOTAL
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# 147   54   61   56  183  172  228  110  241              1260
# 211   77   80  148  237   98   30   99    8              1016
# 216  241  200   31  218  122  183   34  118              1420
# 34   147  195  115   61   69  208  155   96              1203
# 174   27   39   40   99  241   11   92  114               838
# 102  131    8  130   22  225   80  152  159              1032
# 129   30  122   87  142  245  202   97   40              1280
# 219  226  147  153  217  242  154  129   39              1585
# 186   37  123  168   12  152  105  225   57              1072
# 120  243  146   39  216   50  177  208   36              1434
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# COLUMN TOTAL
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# 1538 1213 1121  967 1407 1616 1378 1301  908             12140
```

If you can use `numpy`, use it ! It's simpler :)
Hope that help !

Answer (score 0):

Here it is just a little cleaner. I'm using numpy instead of random. This way your random table array persists as you need it. Also notice how `stringList` is passed to the format string to make less typing.

```
import numpy as np

dash = "-" * 62

print("Random Integer Table:")

print(dash)
print("{:<10s} {:>45s}".format("RANDOM INTEGERS", "ROW TOTAL"))
print(dash)


array_size = (10, 10)

random_array = np.random.random_integers(1, 251, size=array_size)

for i in range(array_size[0]):
    random_list = [j for j in random_array[i, :]]
    stringList = [str(j) for j in random_list]
    row_total = sum(random_list)
    print("{:<3} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4}".format(*stringList), "{:17d}".format(row_total))


print(dash)
print("COLUMN TOTAL")
print(dash)
column_totals = random_array.sum(axis=0)
print(" ".join(column_totals.astype(str)))
```

> ```
> Random Integer Table:
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> RANDOM INTEGERS                                     ROW TOTAL
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> 25   227  148  226  104  244   84   89   38   58              1243
> 86    52  110  176  147    9   80  214    7  249              1130
> 135  106   27   70    2   69  166  115   46  230               966
> 214  247   39   34  198   99  226   24  106   23              1210
> 159    6   76   99   89  177   83   57  224  155              1125
> 147  207   85  241  144  162  121  209    9   91              1416
> 78   144   73  240  226  164  167  207   37  171              1507
> 52     8  230   42  243   12  213  179  203   34              1216
> 203  116   44    8  198  212   92  162  179  144              1358
> 82    46  113  183  209   37   71  110  203    7              1061
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> COLUMN TOTAL
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> 1181 1159 945 1319 1560 1185 1303 1366 1052 1162
> ```

Comment: This is also another way of doing it. Thank you for the advice, it's always appreciated!